# ASP.net: Scrape Part of webage

Tags: asp.net, scrape

```
     Dim url As New Uri("http://www.testpage.com")
    If url.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp Then
        'Create Request Object
        Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        'Set Request Method
        objRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.[Get]
        'Get response from requested url
        Dim objResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(objRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        'Read response in stream reader
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim tmp As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        objResponse.Close()
        'Set response data to container
        Label1.Text = tmp
    End If
```

How Would I only scrape part of a webpage..The code succesfulyl get the full html content.

For Example..I want to scrape eveyrthing between `<div id="content"> </div>`

Comment: Your can't scrape part, but you can parse your result using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the page's full html content in a string variable, you can use Regular Expressions over this string to return the parts you want to extract.

Since you have not provided details on what you want to extract, I will provide you with a link on how to use Regular Expressions.

A short tutorial on Regular Expressions can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)